# Ionic Zip - Pack whole directory keeping subdirectories and iterate through all files

Tags: c#, loops, zip

I want to pack a directory in C# using Ionic Zip. Normally I would just use this piece of code:

```
using (ZipFile pack = new ZipFile())
{      
    pack.AddDirectory(defPackageCreationPath + "\\installfiles", "");            
    pack.Save(outputPath + "\\package.mpp");
}
```

This is working fine, however I need to iterate through each file being packed to check for characters in their filenames, as I have some files that gets corrupted when packed, if they contain specific characters.

What is important too is that the directory to add contains sub directories too, and those needs to be carried over to the zip file and created inside it.

How?

Comment: Can you rename the files before you zip them? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can easily get a string array of all files including sub directories. using the Directory class

Like so

```
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"M:\Backup", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string file in Files)
{
    DoTests(file);
}
```

This will include the path to the files.

You will need System.IO;

```
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
using (ZipFile pack = new ZipFile())
{
    pack.AddProgress += (s, eventArgs) =>
        {
            // check if EventType is Adding_AfterAddEntry or NullReferenceException will be thrown
            if (eventArgs.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Adding_AfterAddEntry)
            {
                // Do the replacement here.
                // eventArgs.CurrentEntry is the current file processed and
                // eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName holds the file name
                //
                // Example: all files will begin with __
                eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName = "___" + eventArgs.CurrentEntry.FileName;
            }
        };

        pack.AddDirectory(defPackageCreationPath + "\\installfiles", "");            
        pack.Save(outputPath + "\\package.mpp");
    }
}
```